# Need to disable/enable WiFi adaptor on every startup to make it work

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I've just done a clean install of Windows 10 on an old laptop (Lenovo E320), with an Intel Wireless N-1000 network adaptor. Every time the computer starts up, the WiFi won't connect, and when I check the device properties it has a "Device Cannot Start (Code 10)" error.

To fix this, all I have to do is go to the "Driver" tab and disable/enable the device, and the Wifi connects instantly and is rock solid. But I have to do this *every* - *single* - *time* I start the computer, and it's driving me insane.

I've tried everything I can think of, uninstalled and re-installed drivers for the device in question (multiple different versions), power management devices/settings/software, tried various bloatware from Intel and Lenovo, completely re-installed the OS, nothing works.

Some very old forum posts suggested it may have something to do with UEFI/Legacy BIOS settings, but that's a bit beyond me unfortunately. The laptop also has a WiFi on/off function key which I've noticed doesn't work. I think this may be connected but I've been unable to get the function key working either.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated. At this point I'd be happy enough if I could have some sort of script run on startup that disabled/enabled the WiFi for me.

Comment: There is no official Windows 10 support for [Lenovo E320](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e320). Have you installed wireless drivers in compatibility mode?

Comment: @alljamin thanks for your comment. There's no official support from Intel for this device in Win10 either, I thought it was worth a shot regardless! I tried installing in compatibility mode, no luck there either. But as noted below, this problem isn't as annoying as I first thought, so I'll probably just live with it for now.

Comment: You can of course live with it, or you can go back to 8.1 or 7 with all the compatible drivers software available.

Comment: **Updated 2021 Windows 10 answer:** Open the Device Manager, expand Network adapters, uninstall the problematic interface, and click Action > Scan for hardware changes.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry I am reviving an old thread, I found a solution to this problem, and others like me who google and find this thread might like to know how I fixed mine.

I went into the adaptor settings and then into configure on the "Connect using" option.
This brings up the wireless network device settings.
From there you can choose power management and deselect "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
After this it resolved the issue on two different laptops for me.
This was on both an MSI GS70 stealth and a Microsoft Surface 3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after I initially performed a clean install of Windows 10 on my 9-year-old laptop.  After quite a bit of online research, I was able to alleviate the problem by disabling the `Fast Startup` function:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Select `Power Options`

   [image: Power Options]
3. Select `Choose what the power buttons do` on the upper-left

   [image: Choose what the power buttons do]
4. Select `Change settings that are currently unavailable`

   [image: Change settings that are currently unavailable]
5. Scroll to the bottom of the window and uncheck the box associated with `Turn on fast startup`

   [image: Turn on fast startup]
6. Click the button to `Save changes`
7. Reboot your system

(Source: [The Pros and Cons of Windows 10’s “Fast Startup” Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/))

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions, but unfortunately this didn't work. However, I did discover something interesting in the process. Through all my previous messing about I had been *restarting* rather than shut-down/switch-on. After trying out the shut-down/switch-on (which I've now learned is more akin to hibernation in Win10), the WiFi doesn't need to be disabled/enabled. It appears that it's only on a full reboot that the device won't start. A bit weird, but considering how rarely I actually reboot, this probably won't cause as many hassles as I thought.

Comment: Glad to hear that you made some progress.

Answer (score 0):

Right click and proprties for your wifi adaptor, click "advance" tab, choose "EnableAdaptivity" and change option as "Disable". Take a try this if you must disable/enable your wifi card to connect network on every start of windows.